In Starcraft 1, who controls the neutral mobs?
I've heard that Starcraft 1 (and Brood War) use a direct peer-to-peer networking system for multiplayer games, as opposed to a central authoritative server. However, there are also neutral mobs such as the kakaru and ursadon that move around during the gameplay. If neither player controls these mobs, then how does the game determine their movements?
If the mob movement is determined on one of the machines, then what would stop a hacking Zerg player from placing Parasite on a mob, and moving the mob into the enemy base?

They aren't controlled. They are just doodads that have an ability they use on autocast that makes them move around a little.

@A.bakker, if that's the case, do they move differently on the machines?

@tnavidi nope, they are just the same as the Crystals you harvest, except they are attackable and have a walk ability.

That's interesting, but still leaves the question of how that resulting movement is determined. I guess it could be deterministic based on many parts of the game state. But obviously the critters' movement is subject to unit collision so it's subject to some unpredictable changes. I'd be curious if a hacker could just override the critter movement for both machines anyways.
